# Assign environment variable to system properties in JBoss properties-service.xml

Tags: java, xml, jboss, environment-variables, system-properties

I'm trying to set a value to a property defined in properties-service.xml in JBOSS. The value will be coming from an environment variable.

Say I have an environment variable **MQUSER**. In Unix based OS, you get the value of the variable using this notation:
**$MQUSER**
For Windows:
**%MQUSER%**

In my properties-service.xml file, I declare a property named **mq.user**.
Is it possible to set the value of my property from an environment variable, just like this?

```
mq.user=$MQUSER
```